# I tried crontab but it doesn't work, it does not see the directory of file

Tags: cron

I have created a crontab on Amazon linux 2 ami and I have created a cronjob in the crontab:

```
00 * * * * /var/www/html/cront.sh
01 * * * * /var/www/html/cront2.sh
30 * * * * /var/www/html/cront.sh
31 * * * * /var/www/html/cront2.sh
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

EDIT: I tried manually to execute the script and I have noticed that if I print on bash:

```
./var/www/html/cront.sh
```

doesn't work but if I printf:

```
./cront.sh
```

it works. (but I have to stay in the var / www / html directory)
Why this problem? How can I run a cronjob that works?

Thanks

Comment: If you are in, say, `/home/founder` and you run `./var/www/html/cront.sh`, it will try to find the file at `/home/founder/var/www/html/cront.sh`, which presumably does not exist. The leading dot makes the path relative to the current directory. Run it without it: `/var/www/html/cront.sh`. If your script relies on being in a specific directory, use `cd blahblahblah` at the top of it to change the current directory to where you want it to be, or hardcode the paths inside the scripts as absolute paths. Unfortunately, that's as much as is possible to say without actually seeing your script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you check the permissions on those scripts ?

Also, maybe try changing your entries to :

```
00 * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/html/cront.sh
01 * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/html/cront2.sh
30 * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/html/cront.sh
31 * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/html/cront2.sh
```

See if that works.

**EDIT** : Since this worked, I'll add a quick explanation *why* this could fix things...

First, it is possible that the scripts do not have execution permissions ('x') for the user of which the crontab is made. Calling the script trough the interpreter explicitly bypasses this, as the scripts are no longer attempted to be executed, but rather just read.

The second possibility is that the shell scripts use bash specific syntax. The default shell for cron is `sh`, a much more basic and limited shell than `bash`. Calling the bash interpreter specifically solves this. Note that you can also specify the desired interpreter for a script with shebangs (`#!/bin/bash`) on the first line.